# Placing arrays side by side

Tags: arrays

I want to place three arrays side by side. They all should be aligned by their top line. How can I do that with the following arrays:

```
\[
\begin{array}{c c | c}
p   &   q   &   p   \land   q   \\ \hline
1   &   1   &   1 \\
1   &   0   &   0 \\
0   &   1   &   0 \\
0   &   0   &   0 \\
\end{array}
\]

\[
\begin{array}{c c | c}
p   &   q   &   p   \lor    q   \\ \hline
1   &   1   &   1 \\
1   &   0   &   1 \\
0   &   1   &   1 \\
0   &   0   &   0 \\
\end{array}
\]

\[
\begin{array}{c | c}
p   &   \lnot p \\ \hline
1   &   0 \\
0   &   1 \\
\end{array}
\]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Write them in one equation, without empty lines between them. See answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}[t]{c c | c}
p   &   q   &   p   \land   q   \\ \hline
1   &   1   &   1 \\
1   &   0   &   0 \\
0   &   1   &   0 \\
0   &   0   &   0 \\
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}[t]{c c | c}
p   &   q   &   p   \lor    q   \\ \hline
1   &   1   &   1 \\
1   &   0   &   1 \\
0   &   1   &   1 \\
0   &   0   &   0 \\
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}[t]{c | c}
p   &   \lnot p \\ \hline
1   &   0 \\
0   &   1 \\
\end{array}
\]
```

[image]

or if you remove arrays' positioning options `[t]` in above MWE, you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Zarko.

Comment: @NilsK, you are welcome!